# Xamarin Forms - Getting Jar file for standard libraries?

Tags: java, android, .net, visual-studio, xamarin

I'm an absolute beginner to Xamarin Forms. I found that if I want to use java libraries in Xamarin, I need to have a `Java Xamarin Bindings` project. So I have created that in Visual Studio. From there, I know that I need the jar file.

I am trying to find where to easily obtain jar files for standard Android/Java libraries. For example, I am trying to obtain this simple `Android.net` library here, which happens to reference a `ConnectivityManager` Class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager

Where can I simply get this jar file for importing?

I have tried searching on google, but what pops up are locations telling you to get the bindings project as mentioned above, and assume you already have the jar file.

Comment: Standard Android library bindings are already provided by Mictosoft

Comment: Yea, you're right. I thought that might be the case a few seconds before I saw your answer. Thanks.